# How to get the Designation of the User from AdminDirectory

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I was able to get the user name from the below code, is there a way to get the user's designation (or mobile number or work location?)

```
  function getUser() {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var employee = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName;
  Logger.log('User data:\n%s', JSON.stringify(employee, null, 2));
  console.log(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Using the same `AdminDirectory.Users.get()` method you can obtain phone numbers and work locations by specifying the fields you want on the return.*

#### Example:

The method has a large response body which can be seen in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource).

You can see in this resource the two pieces of data you are looking for:

> **`phones[]`:** `list`
>
> > A list of the user's phone numbers. The maximum allowed data size for this field is 1Kb.

---

> **`locations[]`:** `list`
>
> > The user's locations. The maximum allowed data size for this field is 10Kb.

You can then filter out the data you desire with sub categories, for example `phones[].type` or `locations[].area`.

In order to retrieve, for example, phone numbers, you can filter the requeest in the same way:

```
var employee = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user);
var phones = employee.phones
var loc = employee.locations
Logger.log('User data:');
Logger.log(phones);
Logger.log(loc);
```

Will yield a log with the following format:

```
[20-11-02 12:12:28:243 CET] User data:
[20-11-02 12:12:28:247 CET] [{type=home, value=123456789}, {value=987654321, type=mobile}]
[20-11-02 12:12:28:250 CET] [{floorSection=Upper, floorName=Floor 12, type=desk, buildingId=5, area=cityView}]
```

#### References:

- [Users | Directory API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users)